# Datatables serverside search and sort with alias

Tags: jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

Congrats for DT. Awesome job. 
I have one situation here:
Using server-side, i need using  "alias" for columns, because the join is at same table:

Table location
Location source
Location destiny

**So, in $joinQuery:**
..

```
LEFT JOIN localidad GO ON A.mxv_loc_ori_fk = GO.loc_id
LEFT JOIN localidad GD ON A.mxv_loc_dest_fk = GD.loc_id
```

..

**And, in $columns:**

```
array(
       array( 'db' => '(`GO`.`loc_nombre`) as origen', 'dt' => "origen", 'field' => 'origen'),
       array( 'db' => '(`GD`.`loc_nombre`) as destino', 'dt' => 'destino', 'field' => 'destino' )
);
```

**And, in JS: **

```
"columns": [
    {"data":"origen"},
    {"data":"destino"}
]
```

ALL GOOD at this point! The columns show the info correctly.
The problem is at the moment at i try to SEARCH and FILTER. 
I cannot understand why, but it doesn't work!

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Ok this was my resolution for the problem:

create a view in mysql for "localidad" (eg: view_localidad), so the SQL server-side part change to:

```
LEFT JOIN view_localidad GO ON A.mxv_loc_ori_fk = GO.vloc_id
LEFT JOIN localidad GD ON A.mxv_loc_dest_fk = GD.loc_id
```

At the moment, works great!